# How to increment parent row dynamically in angular ui tree

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[Plunker.](https://plnkr.co/edit/dlG6bJcBP8jaxhVEZ4wq?p=preview)

In this plunker I have maintained `+` and `++`. 
`+` for increment the parent rows and `++` for increment the child rows.

Here `++` is incrementing correctly. and '+' also incrementing correctly,
if I click on `++` then it will add one child row for parent.

then if I click on `+` button for it should add another child row for parent. but it is adding another main row.

Here I got the perticular row with this keyword in html. Like that How can I get parent object of the child row what we have clicked.

```
ng-click="newSubItem(this)"//here This keyword will give the current object.
```

**controller:-**

```
$scope.newSubItem = function(scope) {
      var nodeData = scope.$modelValue;
      nodeData.items.push({
        id: nodeData.id * 10 + nodeData.items.length,
        rowId: nodeData.rowId + '.' + (nodeData.items.length + 1),
        items: []
      });
    };
```

Like this I want to increment the current object and push into the items[] array.so The current object will comes under parent object.

Finally how can I get the parent object of the current object.

Comment: your question is little ambiguous, you should add a + button for only main rows, and then the + button in the tree should add a child in that parent

Comment: let me add an answer if it doesn't fit your requirement then let me know

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok now update your addParentRow function with this only

```js
 $scope.addParentRow = function(scope) {

  if (scope.$nodeScope.$parentNodeScope) {
    var nodeData = scope.$nodeScope.$parentNodeScope.$modelValue
    nodeData.items.push({
      id: nodeData.id * 10 + nodeData.items.length,
      rowId: nodeData.rowId + '.' + (nodeData.items.length + 1),
      items: []
    });
  } else {
    var lastObj = $scope.list[$scope.list.length - 1];
    var rowItem = {
      "id": parseFloat(lastObj.id) + 1,
      "rowId": parseFloat(lastObj.rowId) + 1,
      "items": []
    }
    $scope.list.push(rowItem);
  }
}
```

Here is the [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/dlG6bJcBP8jaxhVEZ4wq?p=preview)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45544608/angular-ui-tree-incrementing-is-duplicating

Comment: have you found the problem