# angular Ui tree incrementing is duplicating

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[My Plunker.](https://plnkr.co/edit/dlG6bJcBP8jaxhVEZ4wq?p=preview)

In My plunker if I add some childs, then if I remove one of child record then if I add rows the rows are duplicating.

```
$scope.newSubItem = function(scope) {
  var nodeData = scope.$modelValue;
  nodeData.items.push({
    id: nodeData.id * 10 + nodeData.items.length,
    rowId: nodeData.rowId + '.' + (nodeData.items.length + 1),
    items: []
  });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of adding nodeData.items.lenght add this for id

```
id: nodeData.items.length?(nodeData.items[nodeData.items.length-1].id)+1:nodeData.id * 10
```

And for rowId add this

```
 rowId: nodeData.rowId + '.' + ((nodeData.items.length?(parseInt(nodeData.items[nodeData.items.length-1].rowId.split('.').pop()))+1:0)),
```

Comment: you need to make this change in addParentRow function